# How to use standard ASP.net membership instead of SimpleMembership?

Tags: simplemembership

I'm aware that SimpleMembership doesn't support the standard "lost password" tool. So, it's not so "simple" anymore :(. When I created my site I let it create the mssql tables by itself under a default SimpleMembership. I would like to use the previous asp.net membership and drop simplemembership but I can't seem to get it to transition correctly. I've run the aspnet_regsql.exe to form the proper database structure but I can't figure out how to get my web.config file to reference the old membership structure properly. It's probably a problem with my web.config file. I've been stuck on this all day. Can someone please help? Thanks, Chris.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="myConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
          ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <!--
          ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <!--
            ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.1.0" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.1.0" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.1.0" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.1.0" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="AWSSDK" publicKeyToken="9f476d3089b52be3" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.4" newVersion="2.0.2.4" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Here is an article on how to add password reset to SimpleMembership which includes links to source code http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/04/password-reset-with-simplemembership.html .  Instead of moving backwards from a membership provider that is no longer supported I would move forward to ASP.NET Identity.  http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/11/decoupling-aspnet-identify-from-your.html

Comment: Yeah, I tried it already but ran into a bunch of problems. Maybe I should give it another shot. Thanks :)